# Visual studio compiler errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am making c++ dll in visual studio community 2019 but as I created project its shows me errors.
default code for c++ dll

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

But visual studio gives these errors:

```
E1696   cannot open source file "windows.h"
E0020   identifier "BOOL" is undefined  
E0065   expected a ';'  4
```

I have try messing with some settings which I seen on internet but that haven't helped.

Comment: Those errors are telling you what's wrong. Plain and simple. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: i dont undestend why bool not defiend its defualt this error caused beacouse of bug in update i dont know how to fix them

Comment: `BOOL` is a type defined in the windows header (which, as the compiler is telling you, it cannot open). The C++ boolean type is `bool`, which is written in lowercase

Comment: Root error: `cannot open source file "windows.h"`  check the project type; check include paths; check the version of Platform SDK installed matches the version set in the project.  Try creating a new project.

Comment: You need to run the VS2019 installer again, Start > Visual Studio Installer.  Click More > Modify > Individual Components tab, scroll to "SDK, libraries, and frameworks" and tick one of the "Windows 10 SDK" options.  If you don't know which then pick 17763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**>>E1696   cannot open source file "windows.h"**

First of all you should check the physical existence of the file, it should be in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include" folder in your Visual Studio install directory.

[image]

If the file exists, you should Go to Tools->Options and expand Projects and solutions. Select VC++ Directories from the tree and choose Include Files from the combo on the right.You should see:

$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);

[image]

If the file does not exist,you should download and install the Windows 10 SDK in the VS2019 installer.

[image]

The selected version needs to be the same as the version set in the project.

[image]

**>>E0020   identifier "BOOL" is undefined** 
  **E0065   expected a ';'  4**

When you solve the first error, these error will also be solved.